# Is the multiset - subset sum problem variant not in NP?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, np-hard

If the input for a subset sum problem is a multiset (with repetitions) instead of a set (without repetitions), e.g.

Set $a = \{1282,1588,3590,5138,5505,5777,6198,7962,8827,9838,10137,12037,15296,16089\}$

Multiset $a = \{1282,1282,3590,3590,5505,5505,6198,6198,8827,8827,10137,10137,15296,15296\}$

(above sets are samples, the real sets have lengths up to 64 and each element is up to 64 bits, I'm working with density-1 instances).

In both cases $N$ is the same (183 bits if we use $\sum_{i=1}^n \log_2 a_i$ or 224 bits if we use a more generic approach $\mathrm{Length}(a)\cdot \log_2 \max\,\{a_1, \dots, a_n\}$.

Is there any chance the repetitions could affect the problem so bad that could move the multiset version out of NP?

Everything I know and have read about subset sum for long time says both instances are equally hard, and subset sum and all its variant are NP-Complete and just dependent on the input size but I'm getting a weird different result.

(I found this discrepancy when I was validating the solver works well with multisets.)

Comment: The problem is trivially in NP - you can easily verify whether a proposed solution is correct; that is, the problem has a poly-time witness so in particular it is in NP. It is also NP-hard, since it is at least as hard as subset sum. Therefore, your problem is NP-complete. Did I miss something in your problem description?

Comment: I don't think so, and I'm with you on this. I'm confused because that is what I learned however the solver is reporting a quite complete different time complexity to me. For every duplicate the (asymptotic) steps required to solve the problem are really lower than without the duplicates in all cases. for instance I tried with a 40 elements set (and 40 bits for each element) without duplicates, then, with 20 duplicates and the steps count is 10 times less (i.e 90.000 -> 9.000) and makes no sense to me, this is because I'm asking trying to understand this. Maybe I need to rewrite the question.

Comment: There are $2^{40}$ possible subsets in the first case (40 unique numbers) but only $3^{20}$ in the second case (20 duplicated numbers). This might explain the discrepancy. However, how a particular solver responds to some particular instances of a problem is no indication of the complexity of the generalized problem. Just because a problem is $NP$-hard doesn't mean it doesn't have easy instances.

Comment: This is interesting because SUBSET-SUM is one of those problems that are not "really" hard: it has an FPTAS and can be solved in poly-time if item weights are not too large. This comment bears no weight in practice though, this is just an observation about the theoretical solving of SUBSET-SUM.